# Bing Maps Beginner Tutorial sought

Tags: web-services, windows-mobile, bing-maps

Friends...
Are there any good beginner tutorials for Bing Maps (Windows Mobile using Visual Studio)?
Part of a homework assignment includes developing a very simple app that uses the Bing Maps.

My idea is to fill a dropdown list with 3 values, "Aruba", "Botswana" and "Cape Verde". Upon selection, have the Map display the nation selected in the dropdown.

I'm not sure where to start and need a tutorial that will at least give me an overview of how to do this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following was exactly what I was after! I recommend it. Thanks Map helpers, whatever your location...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsphonetrainingcourse_usingbingmapslab_topic2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Windows Mobile is old. You can only develop applications for it under Visual Studio 2008 because Microsoft abandoned it with the release of VS2010.

You can do other mobile development under Visual Studio 2010 (Win7 Phone, Android, & others).

Bing is newer than VS2008, so even if you found a way to get it to work there would likely be limited functionality.

As for beginner tutorials, a Google search pulled up these two at the top:

http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx

Did you search for anything first or just ask here?

**UPDATE:**

Based on the new information kindly provided by Chris, here are a few other resources:

- [Use GPS And Web Maps For Location-Aware Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315419.aspx)
- [MapPoint on Windows Mobile Devices](http://www.informationweek.com/whitepaper/Software/Development-Tools/mappoint-on-windows-mobile-deviceswp1233343494465?articleID=60200833)
- [MapForums: Windows Mobile Mapping Application](http://www.mapforums.com/windows-mobile-mapping-application-10022.html)
- [How to use Microsoft MapPoint: A Helpful MapPoint Tutorial](http://www.mapping-tools.com/howto/introduction/discontinued-products/)

Perhaps some of that will translate over to Bing.

Comment: Actually Bing maps work fine under CF 3.5 - we use it in a few deployments.  It was simply renamed from the old MapPoint stuff.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I've added an update that should be helpful for Adam.

Comment: Great. I did see these Google results but was after a more step by step  approach for beginner