# driving distance between S and D in bing map in javascript?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I want the 1.driving distance and 2.driving time between source(A) and destination(B) in bing maps in javascript.  please help me.

Comment: Please tell us what you have done already for this and what your problem is.

Comment: Refer this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381523/bing-maps-beginner-tutorial-sought

Comment: Please respond to @EhsanAbd comment.  If you do not, this question is **off-topic** for stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this using the Directions module in the Bing Maps V7 JavaScript control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312802.aspx

You can find interactive code samples here: https://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#DirectionsModule2

Alternatively you can also use the Bing Maps REST services in JavaScript. Here is a code sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427607.aspx

Comment: Avoid updating only reference URL, Please update sample code in the answer !

Comment: These links are to the official code samples from Microsoft for this product. This is way better than just dropping in code sample into this response as it has details about what the code does and links to all the resources around this. I've been a moderator on Microsoft forums for over a decade and found this to be a much better way to help developers.

Comment: I meant about the simple code snippet to get an idea. there is always chance for getting page updated. even w3c, MDN does that. this is my opinion.

Comment: Those pages haven't changed in 7 years. When they do this version of the product will be retired and this whole thread and tag will no longer be valid.

Comment: Also, if those pages are changed, they will likely have update content that is an improvement over the current content, which is better than having a stale code snippet.

Comment: Thats nice. I'm happy. if @shhivvaa get his answer. let me try your approach in other questions

Comment: The specific credentials are invalid. You can sign up for a free developer account is what im getting.

Comment: Not sure why you are posting about the UI change announcement. It has nothing to do with this thread. In the portal go to My Account -> View or change keys, then create a new key. You can then use this key in your code and the authentication error will go away.

Comment: Thanks for the links they helped me a lot in getting a clear idea. Thanks a lot